# SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904) The identifier that starts with

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I am using stored procedure as below anyhow for some files i am retreiving following error. What could be the reason?:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The identifier that starts with 'D:\DISKSEC\TETRAIBMSolution\TETRA\Data\IDJSKDOSD\Parsed\IOPDCVv3995ReportErgfdgfgdfIOPShun_e6c5b926-fb91-484e-bfe0-9c13a96f' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
```

Stored procedure i am using:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkInsertDelimeted] 
                @InputFileName Varchar(700), 
                @TableName Varchar(200) 
        AS 
        BEGIN  
        declare @query varchar(6000) 
          set @Query ='BULK INSERT "' + @TableName + '" FROM "'+ @InputFileName+'" 
                WITH ( DATAFILETYPE =  ''char'', FIELDTERMINATOR = '','' , ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'; 
        print @query 
        exec (@query) 
        END
```

**EDITED for further discussion:**

```
    @InputFileName NVarchar(256),
    @TableName NVarchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
declare @query NVarchar(max)
    set @Query =N'BULK INSERT ' + N'.' + 
      QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@InputFileName, '''')
      + N' WITH ( DATAFILETYPE =  ''char'', FIELDTERMINATOR = '','' , ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'; 
print @query
exec (@query)
END
```

from vb:

```
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "InputFileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, fileToBeParsedPath)    'fileName
            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "TableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, ReportDatabase.TableName)
```

Comment: I would try declaring them as Nvarchar (with the appropriate sizes or even `Nvarchar(MAX)` ). Another thing I would do (to test it) is to concatenate the strings that you are setting to the @Query var, as Nvarchars, placing a n before opening the actual string, just like that: `set @Query = n'BULK INSERT "' + CAST(@TableName AS NVARCHAR(MAX) + n'" FROM "'+ CAST(@InputFileName AS NVARCHAR(MAX) + n'" 
                WITH ( DATAFILETYPE =  ''char'', FIELDTERMINATOR = '','' , ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')';`

Comment: Make sure column data type is varchar(max)

Comment: i put varchar(MAX) to every column in my table and inside BULK everyfield as varchar(MAX) same error

Comment: Be advised that this code is still vulnerable to sql injection even though you are using a parameter because you are doing string concatenation in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you should use NVARCHAR for object names (Unicode!)
- you should use NVARCHAR for file names (Unicode!)
- you should allow for non default schema tables, pass in a schema
- you should use NVARCHAR for query text (Unicode!)
- you should use `[` and `]` as delimiters
- use [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx)

  ```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkInsertDelimeted] 
          @InputFileName NVarchar(256), 
          @TableName NVarchar(128),
          @TableShema NVARCHAR(128)
  AS 
  BEGIN  
  declare @query Nvarchar(max) 
    set @Query =N'BULK INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + N'.' + 
        QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' FROM '+ QUTENAME(@InputFileName, '''')
        + N' WITH ( DATAFILETYPE =  ''char'', FIELDTERMINATOR = '','' , ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'; 
  print @query 
  exec sp_executesql @query
  END
  ```

As for the error: is obviously you're calling the code incorrectly from VB and you pass the filename as the tablename.

Comment: Hi Remus, look at my main post i added edited bul query and its working right now. Can you tell me do i need still TableSchema variable if yes what should i put in vb parameter. Second question does 256 for InputFileName is the char limitation. Third queestion: What should be columns size in my table?